# Jest.fn() not registering mock implementation

Tags: jestjs

Using Jest 27.5.1

I'm writing tests and I need to see that a function is called, but I don't want it to actually do any of its normal operations.  That's pretty much a textbook case for mocking.  The problem is that I need this function to return a promise for the purpose of the test and then allow me to resolve that promise in the test with appropriate values.  I can successfully mock the low-level XMLHttpRequest stuff and I do for another test, but that's deeper in the stack than I want to go for this test.  For one thing, I probably want to replace the way the function I'm currently trying to mock functions at some point.

So...

```
import * as Network from './Network';

let mockResolver = null;
let mockPromise = null;

const mockGetFromPath = jest.fn().mockImplementation((path, query) => {
    debugger;
});

jest.mock('./Network', () => {
    const originalModule = jest.requireActual('./Network');

    return {
        __esModule: true,
        ...originalModule,
        getFromPath: jest.fn((path, query) => {
            debugger;
            return mockPromise;
        }),
        postToPath: (path, body, query) => mockPromise,
    };
});
```

I tried a few experiments using debugger statements and such.  The function at the top (`mockGetFromPath`) is such an experiment.  Calling `mockGetFromPath` in a test never runs that implementation.

In the mocked module, if I don't use `jest.fn` to mock the function, the implementation works perfectly, but of course, it doesn't track calls or call parameters.  If I use `jest.fn`, it just never calls the desired implementation.

Everything I've found in the documentation for Jest says this should work.  But it's not working.  It never calls the mock implementation, just a generic mock function. I've tried a few other ideas and read a half-dozen answers on StackOverflow, but none of them seems to address the issue I'm having.

Comment: Same problem here. I had to resort to oldie, but goldie (more like ugly) import * as ModuleName, and spy on individual exported methods. Raise an issue in their github maybe? :) Most likely related to: jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules#module-mocking-in-esm

FYI jest.mock + dynamic import seem to be working fine together however I have to mockImplementation in the actual test.

Comment: For what I'm doing here, I don't think spy will work.  This seems like fundamental functionality.  I can't believe nobody else has encountered the problem.

Comment: I just reread your comment and there's something in there that might be useful to me: " I have to mockImplementation in the actual test."

I haven't actually tried that.  If I get to work on this project today, I'm going to muck with that and see what happens.

Comment: I'm having this problem with manual mocks (`__mocks__/someFile.ts`). If I export a normal function, everything works, but if I export that same function wrapped in `jest.fn()`, my function is never invoked. It's as if I just exported `jest.fn()` with no implementation.

Comment: I no longer use manual mocks, but I did have this issue in a test recently and discovered it was due to any async operation I was not awaiting. Once I awaited everything, the test passed and my mock implementation was executed. When debugging, it seemed like everything was running, even though I wasn't awaiting, so that threw me off.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this issue and discovered my Jest config had `resetMocks: true`, which means the mock implementation you pass in will be cleared before every test! The default is `false`, so just ensure it's not set to `true` if that is undesired behavior. That should allow you to do this:

```js
import { get } from Network;

jest.mock('./Network', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  ...jest.requireActual('./Network'),
  getFromPath: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ name: 'Joe' }),
}));

describe('get', () => {
  test('works', async () => {
    const response = await get('/user-named-joe');

    expect(getFromPath).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(response).toBe({ name: 'Joe' });
  });
})
```

P.S. if you *do* want/have `resetMocks` set to `true`, the pattern is very similar. You just mock the implementation in the test itself:

```js
import { get } from Network;

jest.mock('./Network', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  ...jest.requireActual('./Network'),
  getFromPath: jest.fn(),
}));

describe('get', () => {
  test('works', async () => {
    getFromPath.mockResolvedValue({ name: 'Joe' });

    const response = await get('/user-named-joe');

    expect(getFromPath).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(response).toBe({ name: 'Joe' });
  });
})
```